# Run an app on Heroku but database elsewhere

Tags: database, postgresql, heroku, cloud, hosting

I'm developing an app which needs a bit above the 10,000 row limit that Heroku has on dev plans.

**Are there any implications to run the app on Heroku but have the database elsewhere?** (For the moment I'm on Rails/PostgreSQL.) Some examples on alternative db-host-providers would be much appreciated as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set DATABASE_URL in your heroku config to the external DATABASE.

`heroku config:set DATABASE_URL=MYOWNDB -a APP_NAME`

Just need to make sure that DB is accessible using this URL.